# Rocker switch to power supply with unused terminal

Tags: ac, toggle-switch

Fairly new to the whole field, so please go easy if this is a stupid question.

I was digging into the details of my 3d printer's PSU the other night to find out how it connected to mains, and I was rather surprised by the outcome. The power cord connects to a C13 socket, which runs the live wire to an LED rocker switch and through it to the PSU's L terminal. The neutral and earth wires run directly to the PSU. But the ground terminal on the switch isn't connected to anything. I'm a little confused about how this works, though I presume it has something to do with how AC circuits work differently from DC ones. I was expecting that the neutral would be connected to the ground terminal on the switch and to the PSU. If the ground terminal is required for a return path for a complete circuit, what works differently in an AC circuit that means it isn't? And if it's not required for either type, why is it there at all?

Comment: what do you mean by `ground terminal on the switch`?

Comment: Every tutorial I've found on LED rocker switches is that they usually have three terminals - an input (connected to a power source), an appliances terminal (connected to whatever you're powering), and a ground - connected to ground. All these guides assume a DC circuit, though. I haven't found any info on how they're used in AC circuits.

Comment: http://www.wiringdepot.com/blog/How-to-Wire-an-Illuminated-Rocker-Switch - it actually specifies you can leave ground open, but you don't get illumination. In the case of the PSU I looked at, it does illuminate even though ground is not connected. Worth noting that the C13 socket and the switch are part of the same piece, so there may be additional connections inside it I can't see.

Comment: The "ground" (actually just the negative terminal, not necessarily connected to mains earth) in the DC is used as a return path for current through the LED.  In AC, neutral is used for the return for the LED or neon.

Comment: @OskarSkog I get that, at least how it works for DC. What I don't understand here is how the LED in this AC case can light up when it's apparently not connected to either neutral or earth at all.

Comment: now it makes sense ... the ground is connected to the light .... be very careful that you do not confuse a SPDT switch with an illuminated switch ... connecting ground to one of the terminals and power to the center terminal of a SPDT switch would cause fireworks when the switch was flipped ... SPDT stands for `single pole double throw` ... the center pin is connected to one of the outside tabs when the switch is one way and the center pin is connected to the other tab when the switch is flipped